# How do I get this code to print what I want?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to print

"Topic {topic} was created by {creator} on {date_added}." using a FOR loop. I have entered all the required information into dictionaries as per the assignment.

I don't know what else to try I am new. Looking for help with dictionaries and FOR loops.

```
    #1.1
    topic1 = {
        "date_added": (2019,9.1),
        "creator": "Mark Scorgie"
    }

    topic2 = {
        "date_added": (2019,9.1),
        "creator": "Mark Scorgie"
    }

    topic3 = {
        "date_added": (2019,9.1),
        "creator": "Mark Scorgie"
    }

    #1.2
    topics = {
        "climbing": topic1,
        "travelling": topic2,
        "swimming": topic3
    }

    #2
    for topic, date_added, creator in sorted(topics.keys()): 
        print(f"Topic {topic} was created on {date_added} by {creator}")
```

I am getting an error message that {date_added} is not defined. I have tried for topic in sorted(topics.items()) *and* for topic in sorted(topics.keys()) but no luck. Not sure how to define date_added and creator in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Please take another look what your `topics`-variable contains!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: I would like more information on why this question is no good.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that all of the `entry` dicts, the `topicentry` lists and `entries` are irrelevant to what you want the loop to do, because the loop is only about the `topics`? Then you should remove that part of the posted code - that's what "minimal" means in context.

Comment: The other problem with the question is that when I try this code, I don't get the same error you claim to get.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem with your code is you are using a tuple in the "date_added" key.It should be

```
topic1 = {
    "date_added": "2019,9.1",
    "creator": "Mark Scorgie"
}
for key, value in topics.items():
    print(f"Topic {key} was created on {value['date_added']} by {value['creator']}")
```

The key will be the name of the topic and the value will be the dictionary contain the info of that topic. You can access the value of a dict by using dict[key_name]

Comment: Thank you so much this fixed the code. Why does python differentiate between "date_added" and 'date_added'?

Comment: No python dont differentiate between "" and ''. You can mix between them as your own convenience. But you should stick to use one 1 them.

Comment: Strange, it wouldn't take {value["date_added"]} but it took {value['date_added']}

Comment: Because we already using "" in the f-string so there maybe some conflicts. But in others cases, which quotation marks you use should not be matter.

Answer (score 0):

For dict objects, you can do someDict.items() to separate the key value and the element value.

Therefore, you can use for loop to access the key and the value by:

```
someDict = {
    "abc" : "123"
}

for key, value in someDict.items():
    print(key)                #output: abc
    print(value)              #output: 123
```

Comment: What if there are multiple keys like in my example?

Comment: @Scorgie Then the for loop will loop through the whole dict to print every key and its corresponding value.